# AttributeError with Typed variables

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, typing

Hey I am probably being dumb, but I am getting an attribute error for a class that i created and I am unsure why.

```
class pixelOrganizer:
    def __init__(self)->None:
        self.counterArray: np.array
        self.interestedPixels: dict

    def pixelCounter(self, event: np.array)-> np.array:
        timeStamp, x, y, polarity, _, _ = event
        self.counterArray[x,y] += 1

        if  self.counterArray[x,y] >= 1000:
            self.interestedPixels[(x,y)] = pixelOfInterest()
            self.interestedPixels[(x,y)].addEvent(polarity,timeStamp)
        return self.counterArray

pixel = pixelOrganizer()
for e in f['events'].numpy():
        for event in e:
            videoArray = pixel.pixelCounter(event)
```

Here is the error:

```
    videoArray = pixel.pixelCounter(event)
  File "d:\Code\ADCAM\pixelCounter.py", line 24, in pixelCounter
    self.counterArray[x,y] += 1
AttributeError: 'pixelOrganizer' object has no attribute 'counterArray'
```

Comment: is this a full code? or there is more?

Comment: There is another class self.interestedPixels[(x,y)] = pixelOfInterest() but didnt think It was important i can update if you would like.